# PHP connection timeout

Tags: php, mysql, performance, curl, timeout

I'm testing a complex project involving several php files linked with each other by CURL. I run the main function 15 times. It only runs 4 times and then complains `Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded`. When I look at the database, I see that operations are executed **exactly** 4 times, every time I run it. What could it be? The error appears on the line where I'm calling some other php file `$data = curl_exec($ch);`

Answer (score 0):

See php.ini `max_execution_time` setting and adjust. `120`, `240` still makes sense and are ok, but do NOT feel tempted to set it to `0` to disable this limit. Instead fix your script to i.e. cache remote files and not fetch it all the time. In general I expect your design to be broken. Connecting scripts via cURL indicates that you either need API or there's some other design issue

Answer (score 0):

Someone else already covered max execution time, so general thoughts:

- Make sure that you aren't needlessly looping things.  If you are done with a loop, "break" it.  Remember you can break multiple iterations too.
- I've not tried this (purely just thinking), but what about using Ajax calls at the end of the execution to start the next execution?  I bet that starts the executing timer over because you're making a new request.

Answer (score 0):

In the starting point of your php function set time limit for this function to execute. Set 0 for no limit.

```
function doWork() {
    set_time_limit(0);
    /* do your work here */
}
```

Time limit set in curl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to request multiple pages, you can do it simultaneously (in parallel) with curl_multi_*